# Exclude redis cache for certain roles

Tags: 8, caching

Is it possible to prevent content being served from redis for certain roles in drupal 8 ?
I am using pantheon.

**Settings.php:**

```
   // Configure Redis

if (defined('PANTHEON_ENVIRONMENT')) {
  // Include the Redis services.yml file. Adjust the path if you installed to a contrib or other subdirectory.
  $settings['container_yamls'][] = 'modules/redis/example.services.yml';

  //phpredis is built into the Pantheon application container.
  $settings['redis.connection']['interface'] = 'PhpRedis';
  // These are dynamic variables handled by Pantheon.
  $settings['redis.connection']['host']      = $_ENV['CACHE_HOST'];
  $settings['redis.connection']['port']      = $_ENV['CACHE_PORT'];
  $settings['redis.connection']['password']  = $_ENV['CACHE_PASSWORD'];

  $settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.redis'; // Use Redis as the default cache.

  // Always set the fast backend for bootstrap, discover and config, otherwise this gets lost when redis is enabled.
  $settings['cache']['bins']['bootstrap'] = 'cache.backend.chainedfast';
  $settings['cache']['bins']['discovery'] = 'cache.backend.chainedfast';
  $settings['cache']['bins']['config']    = 'cache.backend.chainedfast';
}
```

Comment: I don' think so. The settings php run before anything(very early in bootstrap process), so you won't be able to determine the user role beforehand. You could use $_GET switch or a cookie maybe?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? Caches are per default different per roles anyway, and if you have specific pages with content for specific roles, you can make those uncacheable instead.

Comment: @Berdir problem is for content editors who updates articles but they see the cached data for sometime, so I would like to serve them un-cached data from drupal instead and not from redis.

Comment: That should not happen. Content should be immediately invalidated through cache tags.